# Can't get Twitter trends using PHP

Tags: php

So I'm trying to make a fairly simple php script that fetches the latest worldwide trends from Twitter. Most of the code comes from another StackOverflow post, with some minor modifications. Unfortunately, regardless what I try, all I get is:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
```

Yet this same code works just fine to get timelines, get tweets, post tweets, etc... But when I try trends, for some reason it fails.

```
$twitterurl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1";

$oauth_access_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$oauth_access_token_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$consumer_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
$consumer_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";

$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key, 'oauth_nonce' => time(), 'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1', 'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token, 'oauth_timestamp' => time(), 'oauth_version' => '1.0');

function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params)
{
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value)
    {
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }
    return $method . "&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth)
{
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
    {
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
    }
    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}

$base_info = buildBaseString($twitterurl, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
              CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
              CURLOPT_URL => $twitterurl,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);
$trends = json_decode($json);

print_r($json);
```

Comment: "But when I try trends, for some reason it fails."  What output do you get?  Are there any errors in your logs?

Comment: The error is posted in the question. Bad authentication.

Comment: few hints here: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/11927

Comment: Just for fun, can you make sure you get a value when you echo `consumer_key`? I've run into issues before, especially with different environments, where the key i thought was set wasn't set at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify your php script in these lines:

```
$twitterurl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json"; // DELETE ?id=1
```

and

```
$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key, 
'id' => '1', // ADD THIS ROW
'oauth_nonce' => time(),
```

and

```
CURLOPT_URL => $twitterurl . '?id=1', // ADD . '?id=1'
```

I hope this helps.